# C++ OOP for BlackJack

Tags: c++, object-oriented, playing-cards

**BasePlayer.h**

```
 class BasePlayer {
public:
    BasePlayer(int id);
    void dealHand(std::shared_ptr<Hand> h);
    void addCardToHand(std::shared_ptr<Card> c);
    std::shared_ptr<Hand> getHand();
private:
    int _id;
    std::shared_ptr<Hand> _h;
};
```

**BasePlayer.cpp**

```
#include "BasePlayer.h"
BasePlayer::BasePlayer(int id): _id(id) {}
void BasePlayer::dealHand(std::shared_ptr<Hand> h) {
    _h = h;
}
void BasePlayer::addCardToHand(std::shared_ptr<Card> c) {
    _h->addCard(c);
}
std::shared_ptr<Hand> BasePlayer::getHand() {
    return _h;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#include "BasePlayer.h"

class Player: public BasePlayer {
public:
    Player(int id);
    void placeBet(int bet);
private:
    int _bet;
    int _totalCash;
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(int id): BasePlayer(id) {_bet = 0; _totalCash = 0;}

void Player::placeBet(int bet) {
    _bet = bet;
}
```

**Dealer.h**

```
#include "BasePlayer.h"

class Dealer: public BasePlayer {
public:
    Dealer(int id);
};
```

**Dealer.cpp**

```
#include "Dealer.h"

Dealer::Dealer(int id): BasePlayer(id) {}
```

**Card.h**

```
#include "Suit.h"

class Card {
public:
    Card(int value, Suit s);
    virtual int getValue();
    Suit getSuit();
private:
    int _value;
    Suit _s;
};
```

**Card.cpp**

```
#include "Card.h"

Card::Card(int value, Suit s): _value(value), _s(s){}

Suit Card::getSuit() {return _s;}

int Card::getValue() {return _value;}
```

**BlackJackCard.h**

```
#include "Card.h"

class BlackJackCard: public Card {
public:
    BlackJackCard(int value, Suit s);
    int getValue() override;
    int minValue();
    int maxValue();
    bool isAce();
    bool isFaceCard();
};
```

**BlackJackCard.cpp**

```
#include "BlackJackCard.h"

BlackJackCard::BlackJackCard(int value, Suit s): Card(value, s) {}

int BlackJackCard::getValue() {
    if (isAce()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (isFaceCard()) {
        return 10;
    } else {
        return Card::getValue();
    }
}

int BlackJackCard::minValue() {
    if (isAce()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return Card::getValue();
    }
}

int BlackJackCard::maxValue() {
    if (isAce()) {
        return 11;
    } else {
        return Card::getValue();
    }
}

bool BlackJackCard::isAce() {
    return Card::getValue() == 1;
}

bool BlackJackCard::isFaceCard() {
    return Card::getValue() >= 11 && Card::getValue() <=13;
}
```

**Hand.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"

class Hand {
public:
    Hand();
    Hand(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards);
    virtual int getMaxPossibleScore();
    void addCard(std::shared_ptr<Card> c);
    std::vector<int> getCardValues();
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> _cards;
};
```

**Hand.cpp**

```
#include "Hand.h"

Hand::Hand(): _cards({}) {}
Hand::Hand(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards): _cards(cards) {}

int Hand::getMaxPossibleScore() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(auto& card: _cards) {
        sum += card->getValue();
    }
    return sum;
}

void Hand::addCard(std::shared_ptr<Card> c) {
    _cards.push_back(c);
}

std::vector<int> Hand::getCardValues() {
    std::vector<int> values;
    for(const auto& card: _cards) {
        values.push_back(card->getValue());
    }
    return values;
}
```

**BlackJackHand.h**

```
#include "Hand.h"
#include "BlackJackCard.h"
class BlackJackHand: public Hand {
public:
    BlackJackHand(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BlackJackCard>> cards);
    int getMaxPossibleScore() override;
private:
    std::vector<int> getAllPossibleScores();
    bool isBlackJack();
    bool isBusted();
};
```

**BlackJackHand.cpp**

```
#include "BlackJackHand.h"

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> fixCards(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BlackJackCard>> cards) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> _cards;
    for(auto card:cards) {
        _cards.push_back(card);
    }
    return _cards;
}

BlackJackHand::BlackJackHand(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BlackJackCard>> cards): Hand(fixCards(cards)) {}

// Get max possible score under 21, or 22
int BlackJackHand::getMaxPossibleScore() {
    auto scores = getAllPossibleScores();
    int maxScore = 0;
    for(auto score: scores) {
        if (score <= 21 && score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = score;
        }
    }
    return maxScore == 0 ? 22: maxScore;
}

std::vector<int> BlackJackHand::getAllPossibleScores() {
    std::vector<int> scores{0};
    for(const auto& card: _cards) {
        std::vector<int> newScores;
        BlackJackCard* c = dynamic_cast<BlackJackCard*>(card.get());
        for(auto score: scores) {
            newScores.push_back(score+c->getValue());
        }
        if (c->isAce()) {
            for(auto score: scores) {
                newScores.push_back(score+c->maxValue());
            }
        }
        scores = newScores;
    }
    return scores;
}

bool BlackJackHand::isBlackJack() {
    return getMaxPossibleScore() == 21;
}

bool BlackJackHand::isBusted() {
    return getMaxPossibleScore() > 21;
}
```

**Suit.h**

```
enum class Suit {
    Spade, Heart, Diamond, Club
};
```

**Deck.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"

class Deck {
public:
    Deck(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards);
    void shuffle();
    std::shared_ptr<Card> drawCard();
    std::shared_ptr<Card> peekCard();
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> _cards;
};
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include "Deck.h"

Deck::Deck(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards): _cards(cards) {}

void Deck::shuffle() {
    std::shuffle(_cards.begin(), _cards.end(), std::default_random_engine());
}

std::shared_ptr<Card> Deck::drawCard() {
    if (_cards.empty()) {
        throw std::exception();
    }
    auto card = _cards.back();
    _cards.pop_back();
    return card;
}

std::shared_ptr<Card> Deck::peekCard() {
    auto c = _cards.back();
    return c;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
#include "BlackJackCard.h"
#include "Hand.h"
#include "Deck.h"
#include "Dealer.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "BlackJackHand.h"

Deck makeDeck(int n) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards;
    cards.push_back(std::make_shared<BlackJackCard>(1, Suit::Heart));
    cards.push_back(std::make_shared<BlackJackCard>(2, Suit::Heart));
    cards.push_back(std::make_shared<BlackJackCard>(12, Suit::Heart));
    cards.push_back(std::make_shared<BlackJackCard>(13, Suit::Heart));
    /*
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cards.push_back(std::make_shared<BlackJackCard>(i+1, Suit::Heart));
    }*/
    Deck d(cards);
    return d;
}

int main() {
    // Make two players, one is dealer and the other is the actual player
    Dealer d(1);
    Player p(2);

    // Make the deck and shuffle it
    auto deck = makeDeck(4);
    deck.shuffle();

    // Give two cards to dealer
    // First make the dealer's hand, then give it to him
    auto c1 = deck.drawCard();
    auto c2 = deck.drawCard();
    BlackJackHand dealerHand({std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BlackJackCard>(c1), std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BlackJackCard>(c2)});
    d.dealHand(std::make_shared<BlackJackHand>(dealerHand));

    // Give two cards to player
    // First make the player's hand, then give it to him
    auto c3 = deck.drawCard();
    auto c4 = deck.drawCard();
    std::cout << "c3 value " << c3->getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c4 value " << c4->getValue() << std::endl;

    BlackJackHand playerHand({std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BlackJackCard>(c3), std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BlackJackCard>(c4)});
    p.dealHand(std::make_shared<BlackJackHand>(playerHand));

    // Player places the bet money
    p.placeBet(10);

    auto h = p.getHand();

    auto score = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BlackJackHand>(h)->getMaxPossibleScore();
    std::cout << "Player score with cards is " << score << std::endl;

    for(auto value: p.getHand()->getCardValues()) {
        std::cout<<value<<" "<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that i tried to use `unique_ptr` as once the card is out of a deck, it is in one hand only, but ran into many problems which required constantly moving them around. eg. in `BlackJackHand` constructor, when i want to add to the `Hand` constructor.